# Rails - Amazon aaws LoadError; .bash_profile snafu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I have been working with the Amazon aaws 0.8.1 gem, with direction from: http://www.jeffreyjason.com/2010/07/12/amazon-product-advertising-api-w-ruby/

First, I installed the gem by adding `gem ruby-aaws` in my gemfile, then bundle installing and it installed successfully.

Then I added the necessary information outlined in the article to my `.amazonrc`file and saved it in my home directory.

Then I tried to run his sample script to make sure everything was ok:

> require 'amazon/aws/search'
>
> include Amazon::AWS
>   include Amazon::AWS::Search
>
> resp = Amazon::AWS.item_search( 'Baby',
>    {
>      'Keywords' => 'pants',
>
> 'MinimumPrice' => '2500',
>
> 'MaximumPrice' => '4999'
>   } )
>
> items = resp.item_search_response.items.item
>
> items.each { |item| puts item, '' }

And I get the error: `'require': no such file to load — amazon/aws/search (LoadError)`

This seems to be a common enough error because he addresses it at the bottom of his tutorial by saying: `solution: don’t forget to set RUBYOPT in your .bash_profile via: export RUBYOPT=rubygems`

I tried searching for the .bash_profile file and couldn't find it.  I made sure hidden files were shown, and still nothing.  So I created one and added it into my home directory, but the problem still persists.

Most of the resources online address .bash_profile in Linux or Mac environments, but I am running a windows vista OS (and rails 3.0.7 for further clarity).

Any ideas on how to solve the .bash_profile conundrum and successfully connect to the amazon db's?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bash_profile` is not on window's OS's, so trying to find the .bash_profile is a fool's errand.  The real question is how to modify `RUBYOPT` on a windows system (which it seems the `.bash_profile/.bashrc` is used for on other OS's).

First, close down your ruby command line if its open, and go to the `Start Menu`, then the `Control Panel` -> `System` ->`Advanced Settings/System Properties`.

In the `Properties` section click the `Advanced` tab and click the `environment variables` button at the bottom right.

Under `Environment Variables`, create a new variable with the name `"RUBYOPT"` and the value `"rubygems"` then reopen your ruby command line.